# Postgres check if related table has an entry if field is True

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have a table with a boolean column `automated`. When that field is set to `TRUE`, then another table needs to have an entry referring to that row.

Table A

```
     id    |   automated
    ---------------------
     1     |       False
     2     |       True
     3     |       False
```

Table B

```
     id    |  FK-TableA   |  Value
     -------------------------------
     2     |       2      |   X
```

So whenever a new entry gets inserted into Table A where `automated` is set to `TRUE`, then there also has to be a row inserted (or present) in Table B with a referece to it.

Answer (score 1):

It is ugly and introduces a redundancy into the database, but I cannot think of a better way than this:

- Introduce a new column `b_id` to `a`.
- Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `("FK-TableA", id)` to `b`.
- Add a foreign key on `a` so that `(id, b_id) REFERENCES b("FK-TableA", id)`.
- Add a `CHECK (b_id IS NOT NULL OR NOT automated)` constraint on `a`.

Then you have to point `b_id` to one of the rows in `b` that points back to this `a` row.

To make it perfect, you'd have to add triggers that guarantee that after each modification, the two foreign keys are still consistent.

I told you it was ugly!

Answer (score 1):

It seems an unnatural flow to me, with the constraint you are stating the natural flow should be creating a `TRIGGER` on Table B that inserts a record on Table A whenever a new Table B record is inserted.

But I understand this is a simplification of a more elaborated problem so if you really need to create this kind of procedure, there is still a question to be answered, what happens when check is negative, should there be an exception? should the record be inserted with `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`, should the record need to be ignored? there are two options from my point of view:

1. Create a `TRIGGER` before `INSERT` on table A that updates the table accordingly (Create a `PROCEDURE` that checks if this exists and a `TRIGGER` that executes this procedure)
2. Create a `RULE` on insert on your table A that checks that record exists on Table B and changes record or does instead nothing.

With a little more background I can help you with Trigger/Rule.

Anyway, take into account this can be performance-wise a real mistake if this table gets lots of INSERTs and you should go for some offline(as not being done on the live INSERT) procedure instead of doing on live INSERT